# How hbase handle indexed table consistency with data table?

Tags: indexing, hbase, consistency, eventual-consistency

When there is high concurrency updates in index table how hbase ensure index consistency with data? that scan on index table won't see obsolete data when query primary table.

For example there is "topic" indexed by time and "posts" table, when post comes topic table is updated and also secondary index on time column.

```
# topics table
key: uuid
columns: [title, time]
secondary index: time -> uuid (key)
```

If there is scan by secondary index data may be changed and scan can miss/ get obsolete data?
How hbase handle indexed table consistency with data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBase does not support transactions between two tables in a way that you describe. All semantic dependencies in your data model are not enforced by HBase. If you delete an entry from the Posts table, it is not cascaded to another table, unless your program handles that explicitly